# onClick doesn't work when form action is going to jsp page with Apache Shiro

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, shiro

I was originally logging in fine, while needing to submit an onClick method before my form is submitted (as it helps with some of the data sent).

I am now trying to send some of this info to my Java Bean using

```
    <jsp:useBean id="url" class="plan.URL" scope="session"/> 
    <jsp:setProperty name="url" property="*"/>
```

The problem I am encountering is that my login is not submitting correctly which seems to mean that when I set

```
action=""
```

to

```
action="viewer.jsp" it isn't calling my onClick method anymore, or at least that's what it seems to be.
```

Login

```
 <form name="loginform" action="viewer.jsp" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="User Name" name="user" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>

                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" onClick = "login()" >
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I realized that for some reason I wasn't being logged in at all once I put an action.  I am using Apache Shiro so I am wondering what's going on with the Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

`onclick` is conflicting with submit: submit causes the page to reload. `onclick` might be called but the browser will load the action page at the same time.

Change input's `onclick` to form's `onsubmit` then do your login() stuff and `return true` from it if you want the form to be finally submitted, or `false` if you don't validate the data and you want to cancel the submition.

`onsubmit` is an attribute to the `<form>` element, so you'd do:

**... to submit the form depending on your login() function result (`true`->submit, `false`->don't submit):**

```
<form onsubmit="return login()" .........>
```

**... to execute login() function and ALWAYS submit afterwards, you can also do:**

```
<form onsubmit="login();return true;" .........>
```

and just

```
<input type="submit" ...>
```

without any event.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67173/discussion-on-answer-by-rupps-onclick-doesnt-work-when-form-action-is-going-to).